# Alternative to acra (Application Crash Reports for Android)

Tags: android

I need a lib for automatic-send to my email account logcats of crash application's user.

I using acra but its use an intent to send email (so is not automatic).

What should be use to send (silent) crash reports?

thanks!

Comment: AFAIK ACRA has silent mode too ... but not with email ... so you have to use ReportSender interface and add sending code there (fx using javamail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Examples for ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/source/browse/trunk/examples/CrashReport/src/org/acra/sender/HttpPostSender.java?r=385)

`HttpPostSender` is a fine example of how to implement `ReportSender` which will post the data silently, located here:

http://code.google.com/p/acra/source/browse/trunk/examples/CrashReport/src/org/acra/sender

Comment: I am looking for an example of calling `HttpPostSender` to send the map to my server's api endpoint. any suggestions?

Comment: take a look at `HttpPostSender` : http://code.google.com/p/acra/source/browse/trunk/acra/src/main/java/org/acra/sender/HttpPostSender.java  specifically the `send(...)` method